# Export object or variable between units or modules in node js

Tags: node.js

I need export an object or variable from my app to a router module.

The object is called "page" into "ClientClass".
I read something in SO and I tried to use a global  var to save the object, exports it on end of unit.
This object will be used in the router module.

But, I have no success. In the router module "page" is always undefined.

How could I do that?

Main App JS - ClientClass.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const WARoutes = require('./routes/WARoutes');
var globalpage;

export default class ClientClass {
    constructor(options) {
        this.options =  ...
    }


    async start() {
        const browser = ....
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        // set globalpage to export
        globalpage = page;
        console.log('Done!');
        app.use(express.json({ limit: '20mb' }));
        app.use('/whats', WARoutes);
        app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`Listening on ${this.callbackUrl}...`);
        });
    }
    start();
};
module.exports.page =globalpage;
```

WARoutes.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const pagebrowser = require('../ClientClass.js');
const page = pagebrowser.page;

router.get('/getChats', async (req, res) => {
    const chats = await page.evaluate((includePict, done) => {
        do sometthing;  //Here is my problem - page is undefined 
    }, includePict, done);

    res.send(chats);
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: To put a name to this: you're trying to resolve a cyclical dependency. One of them can be resolved at evaluation time or compile time, but the other must be resolved at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a cyclical dependency. You need to pass your `page` variable to the WARoutes.js implementation. Here's one way to do it:

WARoutes.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

//export a function which takes the `page` variable, *returning* the router which used to be _exported_
module.exports = function(page){

    router.get('/getChats', async (req, res) => {
        const chats = await page.evaluate((includePict, done) => {
            do something;
        }, includePict, done);

        res.send(chats);
    });
    return router;
}
```

ClientClass.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const WARoutes = require('./routes/WARoutes');

export default class ClientClass {
    constructor(options) {
        this.options =  ...
    }


    async start() {
        const browser = ....
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        console.log('Done!');
        app.use(express.json({ limit: '20mb' }));
        app.use('/whats', WARoutes(page));
        app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`Listening on ${this.callbackUrl}...`);
        });
    }
    start();
};
```

P.S.
I am also curious about what you're passing to `page.evaluate`. The first is a function with two arguments, the second and third are those two arguments again. I have a sneaking suspicion this is not going to work even as modified. You're going to need to provide more information about the `page.evaluate` API for additional help with that.

Comment: Thank you very much. It woks very well.